# Firewire external hard drives (quick question)

Tags: hard-drive

Do firewire external hard drives require external power supplies? 
- I'm under the impression that Firewire supplies more voltage (than USB) to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the device in question, but Firewire does provide power. I have a 120GB drive that uses the power supplied by either Firewire or USB to work, and has the option of an external power adapter that I'm not doing. Works well.